# Why class variable read from method and outside are different?

Tags: python, oop

So, i created Some class

```
class Some:
    @classmethod
    def __init__(cls, somevar):
        cls.somevar = somevar

    @classmethod
    def read(cls):
        return cls.somevar
```

Now I tried to set variable outside and read it from class:

```
instance = Some([1, 2, 3])
instance.somevar = [4, 5, 6]
print(instance.read())

>>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

But calling same named variable outside class give me expected output instead,

```
print(instance.somevar)
>>>> [4, 5, 6]
```

What is my misunderstanding about the OOP?

**EDIT**

My goal is to create multiple instances of `Some` that will have their own values.

Comment: Making `__init__` a class method seems very weird. Why are you doing this and how do you hope it will work?

Comment: @tripleee, sorry, I'm very newbie. Without doing it class method script crashes at read method `  File "C:\py\classtest.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(instance.read())
  File "C:\py\classtest.py", line 11, in read
    return cls.somevar
AttributeError: type object 'Some' has no attribute 'somevar'`

Comment: Well that's because the `read` method is also a class method, and the class attribute it tries to access won't be created by `__init__` unless you change it so the two methods are compatible.  If you really really want to do that, either don't make either method a class method, or change `__init__` to something like `def __init__(self, value): self.__class__.somevar = value`

Comment: @EgorEgorov Could you please provide more information on what is your goal. Do you want all instance _sharing_ the `somevar` value, or you're looking for a way to create multiple instance that all have their own values ?

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for explanation! Removed classmethod decorators and it's all properly now.

Comment: @scharette I want to create multiple instances, that have their own values. I did it now, thanks for you and tripleee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, you misunderstood what a *class variable is*. When you're using

```
instance.somevar = [4, 5, 6]
```

it doesn't mutate the value that you think. Instead, what you'd need to do is change the actual class variable like so,

```
instance = Some([1, 2, 3])
instance.somevar = [4, 5, 6]
print(instance.read())
instance2 = Some([4, 5, 6])
print(instance.read())

>>>>
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Indeed, don't forget that by using the `@classmethod` decorator, `cls` is actually the class itself. Therefore, in your case, `cls.somevar` will be shared across all classes. Also, since you decorated your `__init__`, you'll be changing the value of that variable every time you will instantiate the class as shown empirically in my above example.

---

Note that this is probably not the implementation you are looking for. You probably want to be using `self` like this instead,

```
class Some:
    def __init__(self, somevar):
        self.somevar = somevar

    def read(self):
        return self.somevar

instance = Some([1, 2, 3])
print(instance.read())
instance.somevar = [4, 5, 6]
print(instance.read())

>>>>
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: But these variables are not class variables, they are instance variables. If you create another `Some()` object it will have a separate value which is not reflected in `instance`.

Comment: @tripleee You mean in my second example ? Because OP said _Now I tried to set variable outside and read it from class:_ which I thought was exactly the behavior I presented.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I removed classmethod decorators and it exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `print(instance.somevar)` to get the somevar value, but you change it inside your function, not globally

Comment: I understand that, but in some case I want to read that variable from class method

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to better understand the difference between a class and an instance.  Perhaps the following code will help.

```
class Some():
    classvar = 123

    def __init__ (self, value):
        self.instvar = value

    def read_instvar (self):
        return self.instvar

    def read_classvar (self):
        return self.__class__.classvar

    @classmethod
    def update_classvar(cls, value):
        cls.classvar = value
```

So now we can create several objects and see how they interact.

```
>>> first = Some(12)
>>> second = Some(34)
>>> second.update_classvar(456)
>>> first.read_classvar()
456
>>> first.read_instvar()
12
>>> second.read_instvar()
34
>>> second.read_classvar()
456
```

Observe how `instvar` is the attribute of each instance; so `first` has a value which is distinct from that of `second`.  Notice however how `classvar` is shared between these instances, because they belong to the same class, and the class variable is a property of that class, not of any one instance. Concretely, even though we changed the class variable via `second`, the change is also visible in `first`.

Answer (score 0):

It is more like a scope problem.

```
instance = Some([1, 2, 3])
instance.somevar = [4, 5, 6]
print(instance.read())

>> [1, 2, 3]

Some.somevar = [4, 5, 6]
print(instance.read())

>> [4, 5, 6]
```

All is based on the fact that in Python, 2 variables with same name can be used in a instance scope and in a class scope and have different values.

Comment: Even though you bring valid information I really don't think _scope_ is the problem as you presented it. His class architecture (aka `@classmethod` uses) is actually the culprit here.